# Unable to connect my server with Filezilla after changing my name server to cloudflare

Tags: ftp, dns, web-hosting, filezilla, nameservers

Hi I recently activated cloudflare to my domain, and I changed my name server pointing to cloudflare.

After changing this, I couldn't able to connect my server through filezilla. When I changed my name server to old name server, it is working.

So the real problem is with the name server pointing to cloudflare. So can anyone tell me how to solve this. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not your name server pointing to Cloudflare but that you are trying to connect with FTP to the IP address of the Cloudflare endpoint instead to your own server.

To protect you website Cloudflare takes over the hostname and points it to their own servers. This is done by setting up Cloudflare as the name server. But Cloudflare only handles HTTP/HTTPS and no FTP connections. Thus you either need to explicitly use the IP address instead of the hostname when connecting to your FTP server or you have to use a different hostname (like ftp.example.com) and advice Cloudflare to provide the original IP address for this name.

See also [Using FTP with CloudFlare (Cloudflare support)](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169346-Using-FTP-with-CloudFlare-).

Comment: Appreciate your answer. I recently come to know that I need to use cloudflare IP address if I want to use cpanel or ftp access. 

When I try to access ftp via cdn ip address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx by giving username and password through filezilla, I am getting response in 220 bla bla, followed by

Command: Auth TLS
Error: Couldnot connect to server

Any thought on this

Comment: @GopinathShiva: I don't know why you should use the cloudflare IP instead of your own when connecting to your own FTP server. Where is the source for "I recently come to know...".

Comment: Refer http://www.ricksdailytips.com/cant-access-cpanel-with-cloudflare/  . Here they mentioned to use ip address listed in the cloudflare. So I am doing the same. By this I can able to access the cpanel.

Assume 142.123.426.195 is the ip address mentioned in the cloudflare, when I type 142.123.426.195/cpanel => I can able to access cpanel, but when I type ftp://142.123.426.195 -> I can't able to access ftp. Gotcha?

Comment: @GopinathShiva: If I understand you correctly you don't use the IP address of Cloudflare to connect but the IP address to where CloudFlare directs the request, i.e. our servers address. Are you even sure that your FTP server and your web server share the same IP address?

Comment: Yes you're right I am trying to connect to IP address. I did what was mentioned in the above link. In that they mentioned to use IP address listed in the DNS page of cloudflare. So basically doing the same. cpanel is working but ftp not :(

Comment: I am sure that both FTP and web server share the same IP address (event the cpanel share same IP address - which I am using to access cpanel and its working) in the cloudflare

Comment: @GopinathShiva: I don't think we get any further unless you provide clear details about the domain and the IP addresses you use. There is too much information loss in trying to work with examples.

Comment: @GopinathShiva: ftp to 162.222.226.195 is the correct way and there is also a FTP server there. This should be the same IP you also connect to when you disable Cloudflare. The "AUTH TLS" error you see is probably due to certificate mismatch, since you don't use the name in the certificate to connect but instead the IP address. But I'm not sure as long as you don't provide the full error message you get there.

Comment: @GopinathShiva: apart from that the FTP server only provides a self-signed certificate which does not even match your hostname and the SSL ciphers are absolutely insecure. It is still a bit more secure than to connect without SSL but you might switch off validation of the certificate in FileZilla, since the certificate could not be validated anyway.

Comment: @Stephen: It is working I don't know why its not working. Actually today morning(in India), I tried using Filezilla in office, that time when I tried logged in, I didn't get a popup showing certificate stuff, but when I tried logged in with my personal computer I am able to see that certificate popup. Now its connected :)

Comment: BTW thank u so much for your helping tendency. Would you mind telling why I didn't get that certificate popup stuff while I was in office. If I know the reason, it can help me in future.

Comment: @GopinathShiva: I guess that in the office the settings of FileZilla were different - either certificate validation was off by default or this certificate was already accepted as trusted.

Comment: @Stephen: Actually I installed a fresh copy of filezilla in my office today in my system. I don't think default setting would be off. When I logged in Filezilla through my PC, it showed me the popup with certificate , where as not while I was trying in office. When I tried contacting my service provider, she asked me to turn off windows firewall. So is there anything to do with internet settings for the connection failure?

Comment: @GopinathShiva: you got the certificate warning because the certificate on this FTP server is invalid (self-signed and also wrong name). While such problems can also be caused by some firewall products in this case the problem is probably the invalid certificate on the server.

Answer (score 2):

In FileZilla  Host name change to your IP adress. For example: ourswebsite.com -> 182.12.5.124

Answer (score 0):

In cloudflare DNS Settings, under value cell, check your IP address.
This is the IP address of your site.

Let's assume the IP is `123.123.123.123`.
In order to access your website cPanel, use `https` or `http://123.123.123.123/cpanel` or `http://123.123.123.123:2082/`.

Similarly, you can do it for ftp access in Filezilla. Use IP address in Host and you and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re on Cloudflare, you can’t FTP to your hostname, as it’s now being proxied by Cloudflare, and that won’t proxy an FTP connection. You’ll have to FTP directly to your origin server’s IP address.